# PHP- error when trying to get info from SQL

Tags: php, if-statement

This code is trying to get information from a table called R but I am getting an error on line 6:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LOGICAL_OR in get_R.php on line 6

I've looked it over as well as a good few of my colleagues and we cant figure it out. Here's a copy of the code:

```
<?php

function get_R( $s) {
(
$t = mysql_query ( $s) ) or die (mysql_error() );
if (mysql_num_rows($t) == 0) or die ("<br> No data in R<br>");


$out = "" ;
$out .=
    "<table style= \" color:red ; background:line; \" >";

/*................................*/
while ( $r = mysql_fetch_array($t) ) {
    /*.....................*/
};
    $out .= "....";
    return $out;
}
?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: where the heck is `SELECT`? and what does all this do? `get_R( $s) {
(
$t = mysql_query ( $s) )... while ( $r` query what? This is a terrible question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line doesn't make sense:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($t) == 0) or die ("<br> No data in R<br>");
```

You can't have an `if(...) or ...` statement; it's not valid syntax. You're wanting to do this:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($t) == 0) {
    die ("<br> No data in R<br>");
}
```

Alternatively, you could do

```
mysql_num_rows($t) or die ("<br> No data in R<br>");
```

Also, please [don't use `mysql_*`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1); the `mysql_*` functions are outdated, [deprecated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php), and insecure. Use [`MySQLi`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) instead.

Answer (score 3):

You should either use `if` or `or`, you shouldn't use both.

This is the usual way to write it:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($t) == 0) {
    die("<br> No data in R<br>");
}
```

But you could use:

```
mysql_num_rows($t) != 0 or die("<br> No data in R<br>");
```

**Note** I had to change the comparison from `==` to `!=`, because `or` executes the next expression when the first expression fails. I also could have changed `or` to `and` instead.

`or die` is usually used only when you're doing an assignment or calling a function, and you want to exit when that fails. It's not usually used when you're testing a simple condition, like this.

Answer (score 0):

You have an `if (condition) or die(..)`
What's that about?

Either use `condition or die(..)` or use `if (condition) { .. } else { .. }`
Don't try combining the two syntaxes.

Answer (score -1):

Test this code:

```
<?php

function get_R( $s) {
$t = mysql_query ( $s) or die (mysql_error() );
if (mysql_num_rows($t) == 0) die ("<br> No data in R<br>");


$out = "" ;
$out .=
    "<table style= \" color:red ; background:line; \" >";

/*................................*/
while ( $r = mysql_fetch_array($t) ) {
    /*.....................*/
};
    $out .= "....";
    return $out;
}
?>
```